# Program doesn't segfault only when stepping through debugger (gdb)

Tags: c, gdb

This program I wrote to automatically turn my network's auto configuration logic only segfaults if I run through the program without breaking. When running through a debugger with breakpoints, it runs perfectly fine. When run through a debugger without breakpoints, it segfaults. Is there a bug in this program that I'm not noticing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COMLEN 64
#define BUFSIZE 128

const char *program_name;

typedef enum errors
{
    SUCCESS = 0,
    MEM_ERROR,
    FILE_ERROR,
    USAGE_ERROR,
} Error;

void terminal_error(Error e)
{
    switch (e)
    {
        case MEM_ERROR:
            fputs("Memory error!\n", stderr);
            break;
        case FILE_ERROR:
            fputs("File error!\n", stderr);
            break;
        case USAGE_ERROR:
            fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect usage. Try %s [y|n]\n", program_name);
            break;
        default:
            fputs("Unknown error!\n", stderr);
            break;
    }
    exit(e);
}

Error read_file(FILE *fp, char **buffer)
{

    long len;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    if ((*buffer = malloc(len+1)) == NULL)
        return MEM_ERROR;
    if (fread(*buffer, 1, len, fp) != len)
        return FILE_ERROR;
    buffer[len+1] = '\0';
    return SUCCESS;
}

Error get_interface(char *name)
{
    const char *cmd = "netsh wlan show networks";
    FILE *fp;
    // open pipe to parse output from command and run command
    if ((fp = popen(cmd, "rb")) == NULL)
        return FILE_ERROR;
    // read the piped output into buffer
    char *buffer = NULL;
    Error res;
    res = read_file(fp, &buffer);
    if (res != SUCCESS)
        return res;
    fclose(fp);
    // parse the buffer
    // needle delimits the start of the interface name in the command
    // end_needle delimits the end of the interface name
    const char *needle = "Interface name : "; 
    const char *end_needle = " \r\nThere";
    // end will point to end_needle (end of interface name)
    char *end = NULL;
    // name points to one-past the end of the needle (start of interface
    // name)
    name = strstr(buffer, needle);
    name += strlen(needle);
    end = strstr(buffer, end_needle);
    *end = '\0'; // terminates the interface name
    return SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    const char *template = "netsh wlan set autoconfig enabled=%s interface=\"%s\"";
    char interface_name[BUFSIZE] = {0};
    program_name = argv[0];
    Error res = SUCCESS;
    // get name of wireless interfacew
    res = get_interface(interface_name);
    if (res != SUCCESS)
        terminal_error(res);
    char *op;
    if (argc > 1)
        // arguments were provided
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[1], "y") == 0)
            op = "yes";
        else if (strcmp(argv[1], "n") == 0)
            op = "no";
        else
            terminal_error(USAGE_ERROR);
        char command[COMLEN];
        sprintf(command, template, op, interface_name);
        system(command);
    }
    else
        // no arguments were provided
    {
        system("netsh wlan show settings");
    }
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Off by one error in `read_file()`.

Comment: for future reference : if the issue doesn't occur while running in gdb (for whatever reason), you can always analyze the generated core dump using gdb.

Comment: Try the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer).

Comment: This is called a Heisenbug. And anticipating the next question: it only _appears_ to work in the debugger. Google "c undefined behaviour".

Comment: If your program *ever* segfaults then that's a pretty reliable sign that it's buggy.  That stepping through it via a debugger avoids such a segfault (for the same input) makes that conclusion all but certain.

Comment: You are attempting to seek on a stream obtained from `popen()`, i.e. a pipe.  Generally speaking, pipes are not seekable.

Comment: what would be the proper way for me to read from a pipe?

Comment: It looks like you're seeking so that you can "find out how big" the input is.  That's one technique (lately quite popular, for some strange reason) for finding the size of a file, but a pipe is not a file.

Comment: The data in a pipe is ephemeral: once you read it, it's gone.  So you can't read it twice, or read it and put it back.  You can't read it once to find out how big it is, then allocate a buffer and read it a second time to really read it.  If you're not sure how much data there will be, and if you need to read it all into one contiguous buffer, you have to allocate a buffer that you hope is big enough, but then read carefully, and if you get more data than you expected, use `realloc` or the like to dynamically grow your buffer.

Comment: @DavidTran, you can only read forward from a pipe.  Among other things, that means you can't tell in advance from the pipe itself how much there will be to read.  If you cannot put a firm upper bound on that, then you'll have to adapt dynamically.